# QTcpSocket C++ чтение Http GET/POST запроса

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

Мне необходима помощь из полным чтением из `QTcpSocket`.
Я только учусь и решил написать простенький HTTP-сервер, который будет получать GET/POST запросы.

Проблема моя в том, что у меня не получается прочитать весь запрос, который приходит на мой сервер.

Для чтения POST-запроса я придумал следующий подход: читать из сокета всю информацию пока не встретится `\r\n\r\n` (начало POST-data), затем просто ждать с помощью `QTcpSocket::waitForReadyRead()` и только потом читать информацию.

> Мне кажется, что этот способ неправильный, так как длина (Content-Type) может быть абсолютно разной и всё тело запроса я так и не получу. Прошу вас о помощи с
> реализацией корректного способа чтения всего тела запроса.

Мой код:

```
    QTcpSocket tcpSocket;
    tcpSocket.setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);

    if (!tcpSocket.waitForReadyRead()) {
        tcpSocket.disconnectFromHost();
        tcpSocket.close();
        return;
    }

    const QString line = tcpSocket.readLine();

    QByteArray buffer;
    if (line.startsWith("POST")) {
        while (tcpSocket.bytesAvailable() > 0) {
            QByteArray array = tcpSocket.readAll();

            buffer += array;
            if (buffer.endsWith("\r\n\r\n")) {
                tcpSocket.waitForReadyRead();
            }
        }

    }

    QString postData;

    const QStringList allData = QString(buffer).split("\r\n\r\n");

    if (!allData.isEmpty()) {
        postData = allData.back();
    }

    qDebug().noquote() << "Post data is here:" << postData;
```

Comment: Чтение POST запроса состоит из двух частей. Часть 1 (header) - нужно дочитать до `\r\n\r\n` после этой комбиначии начинается тело POST-запроса. Длинна тела (часть 2) - Content-Length. Если header слишком большой, то добавляется вначале заголовок с длинной header, не помню как называется (без него можно расшифровать). Если `\r\n\r\n` - не обнаружено - это неправильный запрос (обычно возврат 400 Bad header).

Comment: Можно смело читать с "запасом", как только будет достигнут "конец" запроса - readAll вернёт столько сколько надо, но я бы брал блоками по 256 байт например - мне так удобнее. И память думаю в высоко-нагруженом месте не нужно мучать.

Comment: Вы не опираетесь на `Content-Length`. Вторую часть запроса надо читать пока размер тела не будет равен `Content-Length`, а не пока закончатся батйты в стеке. То можно поймать баг. Тело может передаваться и 5 минут, и даже час (например если передают файл на 1+ гиг).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я приблизительно так себе и представлял, что надо сначала прочитать все заголовки, а потом тело запроса, опираясь на Content-Length. К сожалению, моя проблема в том, что я не знаю, как это реализовать на практике. Не могли бы, пожалуйста, продемонстрировать эту часть исходного кода?

Comment: Вот тут ` if (buffer.endsWith("\r\n\r\n")) {` надо добавить анализ заголовков.

Comment: Нет, не буду демонстрировать. Скачайте исходники неон, openssh или другие реализации http, там можно найти. Реализация сложна. Упрощённый алгоритм только могу дать - качаете пока не найдёте "\r\n\r\n", обнуляете счётчик, находите Content-Length, читаете значение переводите в int32 или int64, это длинна второй чаcти. Читаете из сокета вторую часть порциями, пока не скачаете Content-Length байт.

Comment: Я только учусь. Мне не нужна супер-сложная реализация. Достаточно просто прочитать хотя бы 2000 символов (ну или сколько возможно). Я вас понимаю, но реализовать это не могу. Гигабайтеы информации мне не надо читать

Comment: Учитесь использовать дебагер. Это ваш лучший помощник. Кстати бесплатный

Comment: Мне надо просто реализовать чтение из сокета, вот и всё :( Больше ничего. Я знаю как получить заголовки, но я не знаю как читать и ожидать до того момента, пока я не встречу конец заголовков и само тело запроса. Любой самый простенький пример, пожалуйста :(

Comment: Само проще для вас `ContentLength = вычислить; while ( postData.Длинна < ContentLength  ) {  postData дочитать. }` QT не знаю. Детальнее не подскажу.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос актуальный. Буду пытаться решить эту проблему.